# ¿Como agrego una imagen en un atributo imagen de un clase y pasarlo a reporte RDLC?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Buen dia, me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como solucionar el siguiente problema.
pasa que quiero hacer un reporte usando reportviewer, los datos de texto los he logrado pasar sin mayor problema, pero el problema viene al momento intentar pasar imagenes, cabe recalcar que los datos los estoy tratando de pasar de un datagridview a una clase y posteriormente a un RDLC.

el error que me aparece es (No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' al tipo 'System.Byte[])

En esta parte yo tengo unos datos cargados en mi DGV, para poder generarlos en PDF o imprimir.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que aparezcan las imagenes en el campo de imagen que tengo en mi informe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo fuente

```
private void GenerarCotizacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImpresionesPDF.ImpresionPDF ipdf = new ImpresionesPDF.ImpresionPDF();
     
        //#################  Datos de tablas de la cotizacion  ####################

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            OrigenDatos.DatosCotizacion dtc = new OrigenDatos.DatosCotizacion();


             //Guardamos en memoria la lista de imagenes seleccionadas
             byte[] ImgData1 = (byte[])dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
             MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(ImgData1);


            dtc.ImagenRP = Image.FromStream(ms1);
            dtc.NombreRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            dtc.ModeloRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            dtc.DescripcionRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            dtc.UnitarioRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            dtc.CantidadRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            dtc.ImporteRP = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewAcotizar.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);

            ipdf.dtCotlist.Add(dtc);
        }

        ipdf.Show();
    }
```

Este es el codigo de mi clase

```
public class DatosCotizacion
{
    public Image ImagenRP { get; set; }
    public string NombreRP { get; set; }
    public string ModeloRP { get; set; }
    public string DescripcionRP { get; set; }
    public string UnitarioRP { get; set; }
    public string CantidadRP { get; set; }
    public string ImporteRP { get; set; }
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea o sabe como solucionarlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

**ACTUALIZO, he logrado al parecer pasar la imagen al rdlc, pero ahora solo aparece una X roja**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando consultas tus datoscotizacion si los muestra en tu rdlc??

Comment: si amigo, de hecho ya logre avanzar un poco, pero ahora tengo otro problema, en el rdlc en vez de la imagen, solo aparece una X roja